# Невозможность атаки «встреча посередине» для DES с тремя ключами?

Tags: криптография

Всем привет, допустим имеется вот такой DES: Ek3(Ek2(Ek1(T))) - у меня возник вопрос
(да, дурацкий) - почему для такого же DES , но с двумя ключами атака типа

"встреча посередине" - возможна , а с тремя - нет?
Ведь принцип атаки с двумя ключами - как я понял- если DES вроде этого : DES: Ek2(Ek1(T)) - то принцип как у матрешки - я перебераю все возможные варианты для k2 длиной в 56 бит и записываю все это в таблицу - назовем ее m1, и в один прекрасный момент я дойду до k1, который является элементом k2 и начну перебирать k1 - также занося результаты в таблицу назовем ее m2. А затем просто сравниваю таблицы m1 и m2 и совпадения элементов - это ибудет "встреча посередине" - так ? НО , почему я не могу по такому же принципу вложенности работать с  DES с тремя ключами? - просто создав таблицу m3 и сравнивая совпадения уж между тремя таблицами?!

Answer (score 0):

Кроме простого алгоритма **Встреча-Посередине** существует **Многомерная-Встреча-Посередине**. Которая как раз и рассчитана на большее число вложений. Именно **Встреча-Посередине** позволяет сократить сложность 3DES до 2^112. Хотя ожидаемая сложность должна быть 2^168.